# How to set Netbeans to ignore Javascript library when scanning and building?

Tags: java, netbeans, dojo

I am　currently using Netbeans Web Application project. I used dojo and dijit library within my project and I notice that when I start netbeans it scans very slow, I believe part of the slow scanning at startup is the scanning of dojo files. As these files do not change, is there a way to command netbeans to ignore a part of the javascript directory? I believe using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) is a solution but this project would only be accessible via intranet.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll always want to use [Dojo's build system](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/index.html) to optimize/minify/concatenate code before deploying.  The individual files used for development will load very slowly over a network.

You may also try the [public CDN](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/cross-domain.html) (currently deployed to Google and AOL) using the build layers as deployed there (e.g. dijit.js) to both offset bandwidth and take advantage of caching.